# Succinct command line steps to create a local directory and push to GitHub

Tags: git, github

I frequently want to add a new local directory and push it up to GitHub. The steps that I take seem clunky so I am wondering if there is a more efficient way.

#### To create a new local project folder called `linked-data` and push it to GitHub

```
// first, create the remote (https://github.com/new)
> mkdir linked-data && cd $_
> git init
> touch README.md
> git add README.md
> git commit -m "Initialize repo"
> git remote add origin git@github.com:sam-berry/linked-data.git
> git push -u origin master
```

Then my fingers hurt and I have to take a rest. Is there a better way? Ideally I could use my SSH key to avoid the manual first step.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way is to [create the GitHub repo (initialized with a `README.md`)](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo/)

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/repository/create-repository-init-readme.png]

Step 2: [`git clone`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) that repo.

There is no step 3.

You can start modifying your local clone of that repo: its remote is already set for you.

Comment: My fault that I did not specify in the original version of the question, but I'm specifically looking for something that can be entirely command line. That is what I meant with the SSH note.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you do not want to go to the web console and have bash, how about a script?

git_initialize.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
repo_name=$1
curl -i -H 'Authorization: token <YOUR_GITHUB_TOKEN>' \
    -d '{ \
        "name": "$repo_name", \
        "auto_init": false, \
        "private": true, \
        "gitignore_template": "nanoc" \
      }' \
    https://api.github.com/user/repos
mkdir $repo_name && cd $_
git init
touch README.md
git add README.md
git commit -m "Initialize repo"
git remote add origin git@github.com:sam-berry/$repo_name.git
git push -u origin master
```

After making sure it has the right permission:

```
chmod +x git_initialize.sh
```

You can run this by:

```
git_initialize.sh this_is_my_git_repo_name
```

Checkout this [link](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/getting-started/#create-a-repository) for github api. You can set `"auto_init": true` to further simplify your steps.

Comment: You are right, a script would be great for this. The problem with your solution is the same problem I mentioned in my question, that the first step before you run the script is to go to GitHub and create the remote. Otherwise the last line in your script will fail.

Comment: Sorry I totally missed the first line. You can use github api to create the remote repository in your script: https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/getting-started/#create-a-repository

Comment: I updated my answer to automate the repository creation step as well.